# How to determine how much jobs have been putten in sleep in the current shell?

Tags: shell, background-process, jobs

The goal beyond this demand is to to print the number of jobs currently in background in the shell prompt. This is typically helpful to know if there are more tasks that one can pop through `fg`. For example one edit some files with `$EDITOR`, then `^Z`, edit an other list of files, at which point the prompt is expected to display `2`.

Comment: is this about posix sh or bash or any other shell?

Comment: POSIX would be fine, variation for misc. shells is fine too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command that seems to work: `count=$(ps --pid $$ -e -o state | grep "^T" | wc -l)`.

Oddly at some point a different count occurred depending on whether the shell was launched within a tmux session or not, but this behavior was not reproducible in a deterministic way, and further trials didn't encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`jobs` is the utility for managing jobs.

```
jobs -s -p | wc -l
```